# How to store history table rows created by a CRUD Trigger in a different database

Tags: sql, triggers, crud

I have a database CMS and a Table.
I created  Delete and INsert/Update Triggers on the Table and the resulting rows will store in another table TableHistory in CMS database.

Now, I created another database CMSHistrory with a table TableHistory.  Here, I want resulting rows of above triggers to be stored in  TableHistory in CMSHistory database and not CMS database.

My aim is to reduce the size of the main CMS database.

Pl advise me.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your insert statement use `INSERT INTO [database name].[table name]` instead of just `INSERT INTO [table name]`